# Insert header & footer to template index.html from external file

Tags: reactjs

I have multiple small create-react-app applications and they all have the same header/footer content. At the moment these header/footer are inside each template in public/index.html file.

The problem is that every time I need to update the header/footer content, I'd have to update them all manually in every application.
I was wondering if there is simple way where I could have the header/footer hosted outside of the application and somehow include them in the template at build time.

**html**

```
<body>
    <%- include http://example.com/header.html %>

    <div id="root"></div>

    <%- include http://example.com/footer.html %>
</body>
```

**html**

    header content

```
<div id="root"></div>

<footer>footer content</footer>
```

Comment: If you are using plain .html file I don't think it is possibile. But for example if your server side is in .Net, you can use .cshtml partial views, or if it is in .php his corrispective.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are new to reactjs. You should learn to use components and it is also a key concept in reactjs. Actually components can define as the building blocks of any React application. A React Component is basically a Javascript class (or a function) which can accept properties(props) as inputs and return a React element which can describe how a User Interface block should appear. React Components help you to split your UI (HTML blocks) into independent and reusable pieces, therefore Components will definitely help you in your case. Please refer to following documentation provided by reactjs.org.

https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: Yes, it's fairly easy to have them as react component or even javascript widget and insert them to the page at run time but the reason i want them to be part of the generated template at build time is so they, header & footer, become visible alot earlier.